# How to send dice/slotmachine emoji on telegram using telethon?

Tags: emoji, telethon

I'm working on a project and my client wants to send that dice/slotmachine emoji (animated one) via API.

I'm currently using telethon python but cannot figure how to send it. When I try sending, it sends the static one. But I need to send the animated one.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Pyrogram:

**installation:**

```
pip3 install -U pyrogram
```

**usage:**

```py
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client

def send_dice(name):
    async def main():
        async with Client(session_file, api_id, api_hash, proxy=my_proxy) as app:
            await app.send_dice(name)
    asyncio.run(main())
```